# How to create a cron job that automatically delete files that are older than 30 days?

Tags: cron, delete

I'm using Ubuntu 14 desktop. I use this machine to backup other machines and as an FTP server for the security cameras.

I need to create a cron job that automatically deletes files that are older than 30 days. I did some search and I think I found the right command but I want to make sure I'm not missing something before executing it.

```
* 4 * * * find /home/USER/DIRECTORY1/DIRECTORY2/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime 29 -delete
```

Do I need to put "sudo" at the before the find command?

Do I need to put "+" before the number of days "29"?

Answer (score 4):

I use one to delete backups older than 10 days and it looks something like this:

`50 17 * * * find /path/to/files/filename* -type f -mtime +10 | xargs rm`

I use `filename*` because they are for backups so they would look like this:

```
filename04-04-2018.tar.gz
filename04-05-2018.tar.gz
filename04-06-2018.tar.gz
```

Comment: What does the "| xargs" mean?

Comment: xargs takes the piped-in output and run it as an argument for rm :)

Answer (score 4):

First, put your `find ...` command in a `bash` script, and call that script from your `crontab`. If you have an encrypted home directory (`cat /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt`) you'll have to store your script outside your `$HOME` directory tree. Keeping a command in `crontab` makes configuring, logging and debugging harder, and the `crontab` command parser isn't as clever as `bash`'s.

Second, always, Always, ALWAYS test `find` with `-print`, and get it to work, before considering `-delete`.

Third, the `find` test "`-mtime 29`" is telling `find` "Find the file's `mtime`, and return `True` if it's equal to `29`. You should use `-mtime +29`, which `find` sees as "`more than 29`", which is what you want. From `man find`:

```
   Numeric arguments can be specified as

   +n     for greater than n,

   -n     for less than n,

   n      for exactly n.
```

Fourth, be sure you have Write access to the directories in `/home/USER/DIRECTORY1/DIRECTORY2/`.

Fifth, do you mean `/home/USER/DIRECTORY1/DIRECTORY2/` or `/home/$USER/DIRECTORY1/DIRECTORY2/`? If `$USER` is for the user's userid, you have a problem: `cron` doesn't define `$USER` in the runtime enviroinment. It does define `$HOME`, so you could use `$HOME/DIRECTORY1/DIRECTORY2`.

Comment: I don't get the fifth point!